# Flutter BlocTest with KeyEvents

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I want to simulate a key event press using [blocTest](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_test) for a Cubit function I'm testing. So far it doesn't seem like I can call `simulateKeyDownEvent` within BlocTest because it focuses on the Bloc/Cubit and not the widget. But when I mock a RawKeyDownEvent() event, `isKeyPressed` is returning false even if it's the correct mocked key?

**Anyone know why this happens and how to get it to show true?**

My cubit function uses this syntax:

```
void handleKeyPress(RawKeyEvent event) {
   if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.keyU)) { ... }
...
```

Event mock and test:

```
blocTest<Cubit, State>('Handle key press, increase layer',
    build: () => cubit, // defined in setup
    act: (cubit) async {
      RawKeyEvent mockEnterKey = const RawKeyDownEventMock(
          data: RawKeyEventDataWindows(keyCode: 13, scanCode: 28, characterCodePoint: 0, modifiers: 0), character: 'enter')
        ..physicalKey = PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter
        ..logicalKey = LogicalKeyboardKey.enter;
      cubit.handleKeyPress(mockEnterKey);
    },
    expect: () => [isA<State>().having((state) => state.currentLayer, 'curent layer', initState + 1)]);
```

Event Mock defintion:

```
class RawKeyDownEventMock extends RawKeyEvent {
  const RawKeyDownEventMock({required data, String? character, bool repeat = false}) : super(data: data, character: character, repeat: repeat);
  set physicalKey(PhysicalKeyboardKey key) => key;
  set logicalKey(LogicalKeyboardKey key) => key;
  @override
  bool isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey key) {
    // Showing as false in tests even when simulating key
    // logical key id - name - physical key id
    // 4294967309 - enter - 458792
    // 117 - U - 458776
    // 97 - A - 458756
    // if (key.keyId == 4294967309 || key.keyId == 117 || key.keyId == 97) return true;
    return super.isKeyPressed(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended being that the `keysPressed` `Set` in the instance of `RawKeyboard` in `raw_keyboard.dart` hadn't added the `RawKeyEvent` to itself because the `handleRawKeyEvent` function was never triggered.

**So you just have to call `await simulateKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter, physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter) // or key or your choice`**

I was doing a lot by Mocking the RawKeyEvent function and, in theory, I think you could still use it and manipulate the RawKeyboard instance and manually call the handleRawKeyEvent function, but that seems like overkill. Fun learning exercise I guess though.